# How to use <hr> between images evenly in html

Tags: html, css

So what I am trying to do is make it so that the line is evenly between images not directly on top of the image. The problem lies in that I am using margins around the image.
The relevant css and html:

```
#infobox_picture {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: 10px;
clear: both;
padding-bottom: 14px;
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 90px;
}

<div id="infobox_picture">
<img src="images/image1.png" width="91" height="90" align="left"  class="frame-img">
 </div>
 <div id="infobox_picture">
 <hr >
  <img src="images/image1.png" width="91" height="90" align="left"         class="frame-img">
  </div>
     <div id="infobox_picture">
  <hr />
<img src="images/image1.png" width="91" height="90" align="left"         class="frame-img">
 </div>
```

Comment: please improve your question, expand on your problem, and create a JSFiddle for us :)

Comment: What are the CSS rules for `.frame-img`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use **class**, not id for the div's:

```
.infobox_picture {
```

and:

```
<div class="infobox_picture">
```

Define top & bottom padding, not top & bottom margin (or vice-versa, depending on how you want the elements to behave) for your div.

Comment: Why not to use the id attribute: id is supposed to be unique within the HTML document regardless of the element type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a horizontal line as a visual effect, you don't need the `<hr>` tag.

You can try the following using pseudo-elements.

If hou have the

```
<div class="infobox_picture">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/91x90" width="91" height="90">
</div>
<div class="infobox_picture">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/91x90" width="91" height="90">
</div>
<div class="infobox_picture">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/91x90" width="91" height="90">
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```css
.infobox_picture {
    margin: 0 auto 15px 10px;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
}
.infobox_picture ~ .infobox_picture:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -8px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Create a pseudo-element on `.infobox_picture` for all the `.infobox_picture` blocks after the first one.

The pseudo-element will have a 1px top border, and the `top` offset is one-half of the bottom margin (plus one pixel or the width of the top border).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/uuWUF/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS and HTML :

```
.infobox_picture {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    clear: both;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 90px;
}
    <div class="infobox_picture">
        <img src="images/image1.png" width="91px" height="90px" align="left" class="frame-img">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="infobox_picture">            
        <img src="images/image1.png" width="91px" height="90px" align="left" class="frame-img">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="infobox_picture">

        <img src="images/image1.png" width="91px" height="90px" align="left" class="frame-img">
    </div>
```

You should use the Class attribute (`.infobox_picture` and `class=infobox_picture`) rather than setting the same ID multiple times as this would make your HTML invalid.

Also if you remove the `padding-bottom:14px;` then each div will be evenly spaced (i.e. 30px + `<hr />` height apart), if you have `padding-bottom:14px;` included the space between each would be `29px` above the `<hr />` and `15px` below the `<hr />` which would be `44px`

Example : With `padding:14px;`

```
    img
    (15px)
    (14px)
    -------
    (15px)
    img
```

Without `padding:14px;`

```
    img
    (15px)
    -------
    (15px)
    img
```